# Dynamically flatten ParentChild Hierarchy using Power Query in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, parent-child

```
let 
  fFlattenHierarchy = (
    hierarchyTable as table
    ,parentKeyColumnIdentifier as text
    ,parentNameColumnIdentifier as text
    ,childKeyColumnIdentifier as text
    ,childNameColumnIdentifier as text
  ) as table =>
  let
    #"Get Root Parents" = Table.Distinct(
      Table.SelectColumns(
        Table.NestedJoin(hierarchyTable
          ,parentKeyColumnIdentifier
          ,hierarchyTable
          ,childKeyColumnIdentifier
          ,"ROOT.PARENTS"
          ,JoinKind.LeftAnti
        )
        ,{
          parentKeyColumnIdentifier
          ,parentNameColumnIdentifier
        }
      )
    ),
    #"Generate Hierarchy" = fGetNextHierarchyLevel(
      #"Get Root Parents"
      ,parentKeyColumnIdentifier
      ,1
    ),
    fGetNextHierarchyLevel = (
      parentsTable as table
      ,nextParentKeyColumnIdentifier as text
      ,hierarchyLevel as number
    ) =>
      let 
        vNextParentKey = childKeyColumnIdentifier & Text.From(hierarchyLevel),
        vNextParentName = childNameColumnIdentifier & Text.From(hierarchyLevel),
        #"Left Join - hierarchyTable (Get Children)" = Table.NestedJoin(parentsTable
          ,nextParentKeyColumnIdentifier
          ,hierarchyTable
          ,parentKeyColumnIdentifier
          ,"NODE.CHILDREN"
          ,JoinKind.LeftOuter
        ),
        #"Expand Column - NODE.CHILDREN" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Left Join - hierarchyTable (Get Children)"
          ,"NODE.CHILDREN"
          ,{
              childKeyColumnIdentifier
              ,childNameColumnIdentifier
          },{
              vNextParentKey
              ,vNextParentName
          }
        ),
        #"Filter Rows - Parents with Children" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expand Column - NODE.CHILDREN"
          ,each Record.Field(_,vNextParentKey) <> null 
              and Record.Field(_,vNextParentKey) <> Record.Field(_,nextParentKeyColumnIdentifier)
        ),
        #"Generate Next Hierarchy Level" = if Table.IsEmpty(#"Filter Rows - Parents with Children")
          then parentsTable 
          else Table.Combine(
            {
              parentsTable
              ,@fGetNextHierarchyLevel(
                #"Filter Rows - Parents with Children"
                ,vNextParentKey
                ,hierarchyLevel + 1
              )
            }
        )
      in 
        #"Generate Next Hierarchy Level",
    #"Add Column - HierarchyPath" = Table.AddColumn(#"Generate Hierarchy",
      "HierarchyPath"
      ,each Text.Combine(
        List.Transform(
          Record.FieldValues(
            Record.SelectFields(_,
              List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(#"Generate Hierarchy")
                ,each Text.StartsWith(_,childKeyColumnIdentifier) 
                  or Text.StartsWith(_,parentKeyColumnIdentifier)
              )
            )
          )
          ,each Text.From(_)
        )
        ,"|"
      )
      ,type text
    ),
    #"Add Column - HierarchyNodeID" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Column - HierarchyPath",
      "HierarchyNodeID"
      ,each List.Last(Text.Split([HierarchyPath],"|"))
      ,type text
    ),
    #"Add Column - HierarchyLevel" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Column - HierarchyNodeID",
      "HierarchyLevel"
      ,each List.Count(Text.Split([HierarchyPath],"|"))
      ,Int64.Type
    ),
    #"Add Column - IsLeafLevel" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Column - HierarchyLevel",
      "IsLeafLevel"
      ,each List.Contains(
          List.Transform(
            Table.Column(
              Table.NestedJoin(hierarchyTable
              ,childKeyColumnIdentifier
              ,hierarchyTable
              ,parentKeyColumnIdentifier
              ,"LEAFLEVEL.CHILDREN"
              ,JoinKind.LeftAnti
              )
              ,childKeyColumnIdentifier
            )
            ,each Text.From(_)
          )
        ,List.Last(Text.Split([HierarchyPath],"|"))
      )
      ,type logical
    )
  in
    #"Add Column - IsLeafLevel",
  //Documentation
  fFlattenHierarchyType = type function (
    hierarchyTable as (type table meta [
      Documentation.FieldCaption = "Hierarchy"
      ,Documentation.LongDescription = "A table containing a parent-child hierarchy"
      ]
    )
    ,parentKeyColumnIdentifier as (type text meta [
      Documentation.FieldCaption = "Parent Key Column Identifier"
      ,Documentation.LongDescription = "The name of the column used to identify the key of the parent node in the hierarchy"
      ,Documentation.SampleValues = { "ParentID" }
      ]
    )
    ,parentNameColumnIdentifier as (type text meta [
      Documentation.FieldCaption = "Parent Name Column Identifier"
      ,Documentation.LongDescription = "The name of the column used to identify the name of the parent node in the hierarchy"
      ,Documentation.SampleValues = { "ParentName" }
      ]
    )
    ,childKeyColumnIdentifier as (type text meta [
      Documentation.FieldCaption = "Child Key Column Identifier"
      ,Documentation.LongDescription = "The name of the column used to identify the key of the child node in the hierarchy"
      ,Documentation.SampleValues = { "ChildID" }
      ]
    )
    ,childNameColumnIdentifier as (type text meta [
      Documentation.FieldCaption = "Child Name Column Identifier"
      ,Documentation.LongDescription = "The name of the column used to identify the name of the child node in the hierarchy"
      ,Documentation.SampleValues = { "ChildName" }
      ]
    )
  ) as list meta [
    Documentation.Name = "fFlattenHierarchy"
    ,Documentation.LongDescription = "Returns a flattened hierarchy table from a parent-child hierarchy table input."
      & "The number of columns returned is based on the depth of the hierarchy. Each child node will be prefixed"
      & "with the value specified for the childNameColumnIdentifier parameter"
    ,Documentation.Examples = {
      [
      Description = "Returns a flattened hierarchy table from a parent-child hierarchy table"
      ,Code = "fFlattenHierarchy(barksdaleOrganisation, ""ParentNodeID"", ""ParentNodeName"", ""ChildNodeID"", ""ChildNodeName"")"
      ,Result = "{100,2,3,51,62,""Stringer"",""Shamrock"",""Slim Charles"",""Bodie"",""Pudding"",5,""100|2|3|51|62"",TRUE,62}"
        & ",{100,2,3,51,""Stringer"",""Shamrock"",""Slim Charles"",""Bodie"",4,""100|2|3|51"",FALSE,51}"
      ]
    }
  ]
in
  Value.ReplaceType(fFlattenHierarchy, fFlattenHierarchyType)
```

Hi community, I am trying to flatten my parentchild hierarchy using Power Query, i reference this code from the link below. My output is giving me null values for each hierarchy level and my hierarchypath column in only showing two codes. Sorry I am not able to upload any files here bt the structure of my data is similar to the one in the link.
[text](https://pivotalbi.com/?s=dynamically+flatten+parent+child+hierarchy)

| EntityCode | ParentCode |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 |  |
| 1002 | 1001 |
| 1003 | 1001 |
| 1004 | 1001 |
| 1005 | 1003 |
| 1006 | 1004 |
| 1007 | 1004 |
| 1008 | 1004 |
| 1008 | 1005 |
| 1008 | 1006 |

Comment: If your data looks like the sample then the sample code would work. If you don't want to provide sample of your particular data, how is anyone supposed to help here ?

Comment: @horseyride
Hi, thanks for your reply. I have just put in a sample of my data

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your `Parent Key Column` and your `Child Key Column` are of the same data type.